# Happens Before relation in Java clarification on a specific example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Referring to the following link 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/QandE/answers.html
The example below shows that Key Statement 1 is not guaranteed to execute before key statement 2

```
public class BadThreads {

    static String message;

    private static class CorrectorThread
        extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            // Key statement 1:
            message = "Mares do eat oats."; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {

        (new CorrectorThread()).start();
        message = "Mares do not eat oats.";
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Key statement 2:
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

The solution states 
There are two ways you can guarantee that all changes to message will be visible to the main thread:

> - In the main thread, retain a reference to the CorrectorThread instance. Then invoke join on that instance before referring to message
> - Encapsulate message in an object with synchronized methods. Never reference message except through those methods.

Both of these techniques establish the necessary happens-before relationship, making changes to message visible.

I understand how the first solution using join can make key statement 1 "happen-before" key statement 2. 
But for the second solution, I cannot understand how using synchronized methods (say getMessage() and setMessage()) establishes this relation. 
What is the guarantee that the modified key statement 2 (System.out.println(getMessage()) will be executed after the modified key statement 1 (setMessage("Mares do eat oats")).
Key statement 2 may get a lock on message before key statement 1 or vice-versa depending on how threads are scheduled.

Also, is there a way to modify the code to make message="Mares do not eat oats" execute before message="Mares do eat oats"? 
One way I can think of is to keep a shared state variable and set it after message="Mares do not eat oats" is executed while message="Mares do eat oats" should be in a block guarded like while(!stateVariable){wait();} and then update the message. Is that right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the *happens-before* with any specific ordering of actions. The point of that relationship is that such an ordering exists *at all*, not that it is any specific ordering. In your example there is no ordering: one thread may never observe the actions of the other thread, even if you use more sleep statements and try to read what the other thread wrote.

If you want to coordinate your two actions, don't resort to `wait`/`notify` as those are very low-level and fragile mechanisms. Use something from `java.util.concurrent`, for example a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: But why does the 2nd solution to make an ordering possible say that a happens before relation will be established such that key statement 1 will execute before key statement 2 if you synchronize access to message?

Comment: No, that is simply not true. No amount of `Thread.sleep` brings a **hard guarantee** that a statement will execute before another. Only `join` and similar coordination techniques achieve that.

Comment: So, is my understanding right that solution 2 proposed in the Oracle Java concurrency Q&A pasted above is not going to guarantee that key statement 1 executes before key statement 2?

Comment: Exactly. Adding `synchronized` to the code you posted will not help it acquire a guarantee of the ordering between those two actions. It is easy to see: that `sleep(1000)` may actually amount to waiting for three seconds before the statement is executed. And this isn't just theoretical, either: when the CPU is heavily loaded such timing can easily happen for real.

Answer (score 3):

The happens-before thing doesn't guarantee that some statement is executed before some other statement. It guarantees that **if** a first statement is executed before a second one, (and there is a good chance of that happening in your exemple, since both threads start at the same time, and one sleeps 1 second whereas the other one sleeps 2 seconds) the second one will see what the first one has written.

The synchronized access to a variable guarantees that a write to this variable is visible to a subsequent read of this variable from another thread. Why? Because that's what the specification of the Java Memory Model says, and because the implementation respects the specification.

There are other ways to guarantee that: make the variable volatile, make it an AtomicReference, or store it and retrieve it from a concurrent collection.

Comment: So the second point above is simply wrong: `synchronized` doesn't give any guarantees, as opposed to `join`. OP's source is not to be trusted.

Comment: I think the `synchronized` bit was probably meant as a simplification. If the waits cause first thread to hit the synchronized block before the second -- and they almost definitely will -- then the HB is there. So it's kinda-semi-right, but not in any way I'd use in production.

Comment: @Marko, I was very confused because I saw this on the Oracle/Sun concurreny tutorial which should have been the source of truth:) Apparently not.

Comment: A source of truth, yes, but neither the whole truth nor nothing but the truth ;-). Being a tutorial, ease of understanding is more important than completeness or accuracy to the very last detail. The authoritative reference is not the java tutorial, but the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @yshavit Under heavy CPU load, or under heavy virtual memory swapping, it can quite easily happen that the `sleep`s are not enough to enforce the desired order. I'd say it is an educationally misguided piece of learning material. See where the "simplification" got our OP---and rightfully so :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you'd need quite the slow computer to have it be heavily loaded or swapping to execute that sample program! ;) But of course in a real app you're completely righ, and Oracle made a mistake (IMHO) in providing this example -- if for no reason than it reinforces the false connection between HB and wall clock ordering.

Comment: @yshavit Well, Eclipse is not exactly a lightweight program, and you have at least that started while trying it out :)

Answer (score 2):

In Answer as described in that site , It is saying that:

> However, this result is not guaranteed, because there is no
>   happens-before relationship between "Key statement 1" and "Key
>   statment 2". **This is true even if "Key statement 1" actually executes
>   before "Key statement 2"**— *remember, a happens-before relationship is about visibility, not sequence.*

Then it says:

> There are two ways you can guarantee that **all changes to message**
>   *will be visible to the main thread:*

It is not saying that `Mares do eat oats.` will surely be printed in result.!!
And by Definition `Synchronization` guarantees both **visibility** and atomicity. So if the message is set and get via synchronized method of an object then It ensures that if the message is changed by `set` method then this changed value would surely be seen by `get` method while reading it back . So if we change to code to this one:

```
class Message
{
    String message ;
    public Message(){}
    public Message(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public synchronized void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public synchronized String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
public class BadThreads {

    //static String message;
    static Message mess = new Message();
    private static class CorrectorThread extends Thread 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                sleep(1000); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            // Key statement 1:
            mess.setMessage ("Mares do eat oats."); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        (new CorrectorThread()).start();
        mess.setMessage("Mares do not eat oats.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Key statement 2:
        System.out.println(mess.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And if `Key Statement 1` is executed before `key statement 2` then it would guarantee that the latest changed value of message would be retrieved via `getMessage()` in main thread.